# Selenium C# - scrolling to a web element

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium

Selenium C# - scrolling to a web element

I tried both the below options:

1.

```
IWebElement button = this.WebDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn-default")); 
// locate the button, can be done with any other selector
Actions action = new Actions(this.WebDriver);
action.MoveToElement(button).Perform(); // move to the button
button.Click();
```

2.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)this.WebDriver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button);
```

Here is the HTML for the button:

```
button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $root.addParameter, enable: $root.selectedParameter() == null" type="button"Add parameter/button
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is option 2 not working, what fails etc? I usually use a similar method, see my answer below..

Answer (score 1):

Try use this method, it will adjust the vertical exibition to an element:

```
public void AdjustElementExibition(IWebElement elemento)
{
    ExecuteJavascript("window.scrollTo(0, 0)");
    if (elemento.Location.Y < 400) return;

    var actions = new Actions(this.WebDriver);
    actions.MoveToElement(elemento);
    actions.Perform();

    ExecuteJavascript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");
    Thread.Sleep(100); //sometimes js take some miliseconds to execute;
}

private object ExecutarComandoJavascript(string script)
{
    return ((IJavaScriptExecutor)this.WebDriver).ExecuteScript(script);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling to particular element can be handle through Actions class or IJavaScriptExecutor.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
var elementAtDown= driver.FindElemet(by.Id("DemoElement"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
//This will scroll the page till the element is found   
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elementAtDown);
//This will scroll the web page till end.       
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");

Or 

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.MoveToElement(elementAtDown);
    actions.Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend scrolling with javascript, like this:

```
        public void ScrollElementIntoView(IWebElement element) {
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)WebDriver.Instance.Driver()).ExecuteScript("window.scroll(" + element.Location.X + "," + (element.Location.Y - 200) + ");");
    }
```

Where WebDriver.Instance.Driver() is your WebDriver instance. The Y-offset is for compensating for a 200px top menu.

Comment: @deeiip: In your case I would just identify the element you want to scroll to, and then pass that element to this helper function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```cs
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

List<WebElement> displayedOptions = driver.FindElements(//span[@class='Button']);
    
for (WebElement option : displayedOptions)
{
    try
    {
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", option);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // Click on Button
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='Button']")).Click();
    }
    catch (WebException E)
    {}
}
```